# Dictionary comparison where one key has more item against two columns

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have the below code to create a dictionary from the below attached file **"Key & items Data Base.xlsx"** where it will store data as shown below.

[Sample files are here](https://gofile.io/d/DxIvqZ)

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyKeys As Dictionary

Private Sub crtdic()
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim NewFile As Variant
    Dim lrow As Long

    NewFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("microsoft excel files (*.xls*), *.xlsm*")

    If NewFile <> False Then
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(NewFile)
    End If

    lrow = wbk.ActiveSheet.Cells(wbk.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim Keys As Variant: Keys = wbk.ActiveSheet.Range("G2:H" & lrow).Value
    Set MyKeys = New Dictionary

    Dim i As Long      
    For i = 2 To UBound(Keys)         
        With MyKeys
            If .Exists(Keys(i, 1)) Then
                MyKeys(Keys(i, 1)) = MyKeys(Keys(i, 1)) & "," & Keys(i, 2)
            Else
                .Add Keys(i, 1), Keys(i, 2)
            End If
        End With
    Next i

    wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

[image: From the Key & Item Data Base created dictionary like this]

**What I want to achieve is**

Using **MyKeys** dictionary I need to check in **Lookup file1 to lookup file3** will be in a separate folder (attached in the above link) where **Key** will be there in **column BS** and its **Item** in **column CI**, to find is there any new Key or item are there which are not in the dictionary **Mykeys**.

If there are any new keys or items found then, need to create one new dictionary which will need to store site name (column A in the look up files) along with the keys and items like the below

[image]

In new sheet or file need to print report like the below. (Kindly refer the attached "Missing KEy & Items.xlsx" file)

[image]

Is this doable? if yes kindly guide me.

Using the **Mykeys** dictionary I just did a mockup test where I can get the exist or non exits item by using the following code. However I'm not getting anything :(

```
Sub pntdic()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim c As Integer, c1 As Integer
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    Set rng = Selection
    Call crtdic

    sht.Activate

    For Each cell In rng
        If MyKeys.Exists(cell.Value) Then
            If MyKeys.Item(cell.Value) = cell.Value Then
                cell.Offset(0, 2) = "Yes"
            Else
                cell.Offset(0, 2) = "no"
            End If       
        End If 
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is `Set rng = Selection`, hard to tell what's going wrong if we don't know on which data exactly the code runs. Did you go through your code step by step using F8 to debug it and inspect your variable values in each step? This should bring you closer to the issue and you should be able to precise your description of what actually is wrong.

Comment: In the mockup i just made the code to look for the selected key in a column and check for the key.. Not sure how to do with the dictionary hence i tried some by referring google..

Comment: @Linga , for now, have you successful get this table https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEq1T.png ?

Comment: @AziMez not yet bit confused with that trying my best using google...

Comment: @Linga you didn't answer my questions. Can you provide a full [mcve]? So we see what input data exactly you use for the code and what your desired output is. It is not clear yet.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i have added sample files and updated the details please check if this information helps to understand better

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, it is possible to create a dictionary of dictionaries. The below solution creates a list of unique keys and associated items for the source data (in '*Key & items Data Base.xlsx*') and for each site name found (by using the site name as a key). This is beneficial over an array of dictionaries, as it means a site name does not need to be unique to a worksheet for this to work.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub crtdic()
    Const folderName As String = "folder" 'set folder name here
    Const noSite As String = "None"
    Const joinItem As String = ","
    
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim add As Boolean
    
    Dim KeysSite As Variant
    Dim KeysKeys As Variant
    Dim KeysItems As Variant
    Dim KeysCompareItems As Variant
    
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim path As String
    Dim dicts As Object
    Dim dict As Object

    Set dicts = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    'Current workbook - source keys and items
    Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    
    lrow = wsh.Cells(wsh.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    KeysKeys = wsh.Range("G2:G" & lrow).Value
    KeysItems = wsh.Range("H2:H" & lrow).Value
    
    dicts.add noSite, dict
    Set dict = Nothing

    For i = 1 To UBound(KeysKeys)
        If dicts(noSite).Exists(KeysKeys(i, 1)) Then
            dicts(noSite)(KeysKeys(i, 1)) = dicts(noSite)(KeysKeys(i, 1)) & joinItem & KeysItems(i, 1)
        Else
            dicts(noSite).add KeysKeys(i, 1), KeysItems(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    
    'Folder files
    path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & folderName & "\"
    
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(path)
    
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        If 0 <> InStr(oFile.Name, ".xls") Then
            Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(path & oFile.Name)
            Set wsh = wbk.ActiveSheet
            
            lrow = wsh.Cells(wsh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            
            KeysSite = wsh.Range("A2:A" & lrow).Value
            KeysKeys = wsh.Range("BS2:BS" & lrow).Value
            KeysItems = wsh.Range("CI2:CI" & lrow).Value
            
            For i = 1 To UBound(KeysSite)
                If Not dicts(noSite).Exists(KeysKeys(i, 1)) Then
                    add = True
                Else
                    'Check for full match
                    KeysCompareItems = Split(dicts(noSite)(KeysKeys(i, 1)), joinItem)
                    add = True
                    
                    For j = 0 To UBound(KeysCompareItems)
                        If KeysCompareItems(j) = KeysItems(i, 1) Then
                            add = False
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next j
                End If
                
                If add = True Then
                    If dicts.Exists(KeysSite(i, 1)) Then
                        If dicts(KeysSite(i, 1)).Exists(KeysKeys(i, 1)) Then
                            dicts(KeysSite(i, 1))(KeysKeys(i, 1)) = dicts(KeysSite(i, 1))(KeysKeys(i, 1)) & joinItem & KeysItems(i, 1)
                        Else
                            dicts(KeysSite(i, 1)).add KeysKeys(i, 1), KeysItems(i, 1)
                        End If
                    Else
                        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                        dicts.add KeysSite(i, 1), dict
                        Set dict = Nothing
                        dicts(KeysSite(i, 1)).add KeysKeys(i, 1), KeysItems(i, 1)
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
            
            wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Set wsh = Nothing
            Set wbk = Nothing
        End If
    Next oFile
    
    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    
    'Write dictionary values
    Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    
    wsh.Activate
    
    lrow = 1
    
    Cells(lrow, 1) = "Site Name"
    Cells(lrow, 2) = "Key"
    Cells(lrow, 3) = "Item"
    
    KeysSite = dicts.Keys
    
    For i = 0 To dicts.Count - 1
        If KeysSite(i) <> noSite Then
            For j = 0 To dicts(KeysSite(i)).Count - 1
                KeysKeys = dicts(KeysSite(i)).Keys
                KeysItems = Split(dicts(KeysSite(i))(KeysKeys(j)), joinItem)
                
                For k = 0 To UBound(KeysItems)
                    lrow = lrow + 1
                    Cells(lrow, 1) = KeysSite(i)
                    Cells(lrow, 2) = KeysKeys(j)
                    Cells(lrow, 3) = KeysItems(k)
                Next k
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

To run this solution:

1. Open '*Key & items Data Base.xlsx*' (on its own) and paste this code into a new module
2. Set the `folderName` constant to your folder name (this folder is assumed to be inside the folder which contains '*Key & items Data Base.xlsx*' and this subfolder is assumed to only contain the lookup files)
3. Run `crtdic`
4. A new sheet containing the new keys & items found is added to '*Key & items Data Base.xlsx*'

The result when running this code with the files provided is:

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you so much sbgib! This is working nicely.. However, im getting the existing Ids in Key & items Data Base.xlsx as new Ids.. If you have time kindly check it

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what you mean by getting the existing ids. I've updated this answer to show you exactly what I get as output when I run this code with the files provided. This appears to match the contents of '_Missing KEy & Items.xlsx_'.

Comment: No worries that's absolutely fine :). When I was running the code in live data (with 3lacks data)  I was getting the Key & items which are in the Key & items Data Base.xlsx... I'm trying to understand how its working..

Comment: Understood. If I could replicate it then I don't mind trying to fix it. After getting the solution this far, I do want to get it 100% of the way there :) If someone else can identify where this code might allow the described issue to happen, that'd be very welcome news too! If you look at the final `If` statement in the code (`If KeysSite(i) <> noSite Then`), that is there specifically to exclude the '_Key & items Data Base.xlsx_' entries from the results. It sounds to me like that might have something to do with it. Can you think of anything else?

Comment: Im working on it as i have some other priority work.. I will start with this little later. Thank you again!
Can we conord the key and Items and check for existence and then create a new dictionary for the new Key??!!

Comment: What does conord mean?

Comment: merging key and item.. i.e Key1item1 and key item2 like this.